# Visual Basic how to get <meta name="csrf_token" content=" from html string

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing, metadata, token

I am doing login to a site (in my LAN) and for the password hash I need csrf login token.

This code loads the HTML from the site and pastes data into richtextbox:

```
    Dim tempcookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://" & ipaddressbox.Text & "/html/home.html", False)
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0")
    xmlhttp.send()


    If (xmlhttp.readyState = 4) Then

        Dim XMLResponse As String = xmlhttp.responseText

        tempcookies = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
        logincookie = tempcookies

        RichTextBox1.Text = XMLResponse + xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders()

    End If
```

The result looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<meta name="csrf_token" content="bVH41vpXbsswSSfNt3Ifw1ZClIKf83Zg"/>
<meta name="csrf_token" content="586yr+JH0dwsLFWZcndPQpx4wGKErie6"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/log4javascript_lite.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/changelang.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/redirect.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/validation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/home.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="all_content" class="body_bg">
            <div id="login_wrapper" class="login_wrapper_dim">
.....etc, continues....
```

I would need to get the string from: meta name="csrf_token" content="**THESTRING**" and being specific from the second csrf_token.

How can I manage to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're working with HTML, use a HTML parser, like [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Then getting the values you're looking for is as easy as

```
Dim doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(yourHtmlAsString)

Dim result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta[@name='csrf_token']") _
                             .Select(Function(node) node.Attributes("content").Value) _
                             .ToList()
```

`result` is now a `List(Of String)` containing the values `"bVH41vpXbsswSSfNt3Ifw1ZClIKf83Zg"` and `"586yr+JH0dwsLFWZcndPQpx4wGKErie6"`